# Trying to set up SSL/TLS certificate on Debian Apache AWS Lightsail instance by following tutorial, but still not working

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-lightsail, debian-stretch

By "not working" I mean the page loads with an `http://` prefix. If I manually type `https://` it times out. I'm hoping that someone who has done this before can glance at the tutorials and see what might be missing.

The tutorials I've tried all tend to be the same:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-debian-8
- https://wiki.debian.org/Self-Signed_Certificate

If I test the SSL connection with an online utility such as:

- https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

I get this error:

> No SSL certificates were found on mywebsite.com. Make sure that the name resolves to the correct server and that the SSL port (default is 443) is open on your server's firewall.

Relevant info:

`$ sudo uname -a
Linux ip-172-26-14-207 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u6 (2018-10-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Running in an AWS Lightsail instance with Debian (OS only) and LAMP stack installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! After using nmap, wget, telnet, etc. to verify that port 443 was open locally but not externally, I remembered that my AWS Lightsail instance was a virtual private server and I might need to configure the VPS. Sure enough, in the Lightsail web interface there is a firewall setting.

Lightsail landing page > Manage instance > Networking > Firewall

[image: AWS Lightsail > Manage Instance > Networking > Firewall]